# flexdirection = row in child View justifycontent any property not working in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

This is my code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';


export default class Dashboard extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.welcome}>
            <Text>Hello mom</Text>
            <Text>Hello Rajat</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.instructions}>
            <Text>Hello Jon</Text>
            <Text>Hello BOB</Text>
        </View>         
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    alignItems:'flex-start',
    justifyContent:'space-around',
  },
  instructions: {
    flex:2,
    flexDirection:'row',
    //alignItems:'flex-end',
    //marginRight: 50,
    justifyContent:'flex-start',
  },
});
```

Where is the error please help me

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question. I could help you but i am unable to understand your question.

Comment: I am using  inner view and when I am applying justify-content property than did not work

Comment: Could you share a sample design of what you want to achieve in the screen ?. This will help me know how to structure elements the screen

Comment: Please check the Img what i want   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tBRDBfqVhXz5aes7i6hzIcCsW6m4FMlE/view?usp=sharing